# Python newbie - help needed in choosing modules/libraries

Tags: python, module

i am learning python.. i want to do certain kind of scripting in python.. like,
i want to communicate 'wmic' commands through dos promt.. store the result a file..
access some sqlite database, take the data it has and compare with the result i stored..
now, what i dont get is that, how should i proceed? is there any specific frameworks or modules/libraries? like, win32api / com or what else?
pls guide me what things i should follow/learn to accomplish what i intend to do.. 
thanks

Comment: A good place to start would be google.

Just an im feeling lucky search for python + wmic turns up a great result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for your project look here
http://tgolden.sc.sabren.com/python/wmi/index.html
http://docs.python.org/library/sqlite3.html

here is list of generic python modules
http://docs.python.org/modindex.html

http://docs.python.org/ - here you can find all information you need with examples.

Comment: Third link obsolete :)

Answer (score 0):

One of the particularly attractive features of Python is the "batteries included" philosophy: The standard library is huge, and extremely well thought out in 90% of the modules I've ever used. Conversely, this means that a good approach is to learn it *first* before branching out and installing third-party libraries that may be much less well supported and, ultimately, have no advantage.

In practice, this means I'd recommend keeping https://docs.python.org/release/2.6.5/library/index.html close to your heart, and delve into the documentation for the `sqlite3` and probably the `subprocess` modules. You may or may not want `win32api` later (I've never worked with wmic, so I'm not sure what you'd need), or come back here when you have concrete questions and already explored the standard library offering.